# Scala, Spring and ActiveRecord with decoupled persistence

Tags: java, spring, scala, activerecord, anemic-domain-model

I've been doing some reading lately and one thing that I've come across was [this article about the Anaemic Domain Model from Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html). I know, it's old, but somehow very actual in Java world. So I'm trying to move towards a more domain-driven design. One option would be to go with the Active Record model. However, I don't really like the current implementation it has in Scala. It completely couples the domain objects with the persistence type (not so bad in most cases but I have a project where I need to store something both in a RDB and in Mongo). Then I ran across [this article about Spring, Hibernate and Scala](http://www.infoq.com/articles/scala_and_spring) and though here too the domain object is coupled with the JPA trait, I noticed how he uses Spring to inject a Notification Service. Can't the same mechanism be used to inject a transparent DAO interface? Have you seen this used anywhere? Any thoughts on the idea?

Comment: what exactly is the problem you are trying to solve? You need to inject a repository/DAO into a domain object as it is fetched from the the DB?

Comment: @tolitius Yes, that's the basic idea. But I'm not trying to solve anything. This is supposed to be a purely academical discussion if that would be a good idea, if you've seen it used and if yes where and with what degree of success.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [Spring-Data](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data), this project provides some kind of abstraction over different data storages.

Comment: Isn't Spring Data, by its design supporting the anaemic domain model?